# Making flexbox container override content height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I'm trying to use Flexbox to get a layout where I have a bar along the top, and content for the rest of the page.  A test case is at:

http://game-point.net/misc/flextest/

Interestingly, Google Chrome already behaves the way I want it to; when the viewport is sized too small vertically (all browsers seem to do what I want horizontally), the content in the `content` div overflows the div, and Chrome displays a vertical scrollbar for the content.  However in Edge and Firefox, when the viewport is sized too small vertically, the `content` div itself is never sized to be vertically smaller than its text content, and therefore it overflows the viewport, causing the entire viewport to get a vertical scrollbar rather than just the `content` div.  Here's the difference:

**Chrome:**
[image: Pic of Chrome]

**Not Chrome:**
[image: Pic of Not Chrome]

Which of these browsers is implementing flexbox correctly, and how can I get Firefox and Edge to scroll just the content box, as Chrome does, rather than the whole viewport?

Comment: Can you move `overflow: auto` onto `.content-container`?

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: See, in particular, the end of my answer in the duplicate for an explanation of the difference in browser behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't go against other ideals in your project, you could fix the height of the containers so that the scrollable area renders correctly.

```
div.header {
  height: 72px;
}

div.content-container {
  height: calc(100% - 72px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to remove `content-container` and just have `content` directly in the outer `container` div.

Comment: That's not the optimal solution, nor does it address the underlying problem. You needed to use `min-height: 0` or `overflow: auto` on the content item.

Comment: I am using `overflow: auto` on the content div.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem anymore in your code sample. Please post the relevant code in your question.